# Can Kobo's drm be removed from their ebooks?

Tags: drm, kobo

Kobo books are hidden in file explorer lists and don't appear in the Calibre library when the device is connected to a PC. Is there any way of (1) making them visible and (2) removing Kobo's DRM so that the books can be read on other readers?

Comment: Please note that this may not be legal in some jurisdictions, even for your own use. Check the laws in your location and seek legal advice.

Comment: Which is, of course, why I didn't make the slightest attempt to explain how you would do that.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it can be done. But it's not exactly simple.  You start by installing the Adobe Digital Editions for PC program on your computer and downloading the "Adobe DRM Epub" to your computer, which should open it in ADE for PC.  Then comes the tricky part: install the Inept Epub DeDRM plugin for Calibre.